# NetBeans IDE 8.2 C++ string declaring problems

Tags: c++, string, netbeans

I have a problem with running c++ code in NetBeans IDE 8.2, which has a string declaring

## lesson1.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int createPointer INT(int element)
{
    int *pointer = new int(element);
    return *pointer;
}

char createPointer_CHAR(char element)
{
    char *pointer = new char(element);
    return *pointer;
}

std::string createPointer_STR(std::string element)
{
    std::string *pointer = new std::string(element);
    return *pointer;
}
```

## lesson1.h

```
#include <string>

#ifndef LESSON1_H
#define LESSON1_H

int createPointer_INT(int element);
char createPointer_CHAR(char element);
std::string createPointer_STR(std::string element);

#endif /* LESSON1_H */
```

## main.cpp

```
// #include <cstdlib> -- for system
// #include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "lesson1.h"

int main() {
    int element0 = createPointer_INT(50);
    char element1 = createPointer_CHAR('U');
    std::string element2 = createPointer_STR("something");
    std::cout << element0 << std::endl << element1 << std::endl << element2;

    return 0;
}
```

**Build successful**, but **run failed.**
Final output: RUN FAILED (exit value -1 073 741 511, total time: 45ms)
When i comment all functions and variables having std::string all is working

What's the problem?

Comment: This code did not build, as `int createPointer INT(int element)` is missing an underscore. Please post your actual code.

Comment: "Final output: RUN FAILED " - where is that output coming from? And what values do you get from your `cout`?

Comment: Except for the massive memory leak, this works for me.

Comment: @Mawg, From my project's output window in bookmark named "cpp_Lessons (Run)"

Comment: @Mawg, This is my actual code.

Comment: Then I wonder about that missing underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Since the functions are called, e.g. "createPointer_INT", it seems pointless not to return said pointer.  Since this is an assignment, I take it that that is what is expected.  If that is the case, you should have functions like:

```
int *createPointer_INT(int element);
char *createPointer_CHAR(char element);
std::string *createPointer_STR(std::string element);
```

When the function executes and finishes, it returns the value of the newly created variables (probably with garbage values), and the pointer values then go out of scope.  After that, you have no valid pointer with which to access this newly allocated memory.  I'm not sure what the runtime error is, but I don't see the point of creating memory, setting the value to that, and returning said value; leaving a memory leak as opposed to deleting it or returning it.  I suspect you'll find the going easier if you recode like this, and you might not have such problems then.  If you do, you seem to be having a problem with the STL libraries with your compiler.  Perhaps you have different builds for the STL link files and the what the compiler is compiling.  You might try re-installing a fresh compiler.

Comment: `int *createPointer_INT(int element);
char *createPointer_CHAR(char element);
std::string *createPointer_STR(std::string element);`    
Didn't help

Comment: The idea is to also change the functions themselves, what is returned, and how they are used.  Do it again, and adjust your functions to work with the new prototypes.